# Motion of particle on parabola

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A particle moves along the parabola $y=x^2$ and has an acceleration vector directed toward the focus point $(0,\frac{1}{4})$. As the particle moves rightward through the origin, its speed is equal to 2 and its acceleration vector $a=<0,1>$

Find the particle’s velocity and acceleration vectors as it later moves through the point $(1,1)$. Assume that the magnitude of the acceleration vector varies inversely with the square of the distance to the focus point.

I have found acceleration vector by utilizing the given information but I am not able to utilize given information to find velocity at (1,1). I thought of using equation

$a_{y}=2[v_{x}^2+x.a_{x}]$ which I obtained by double differentiation. But it gives $v_x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ at origin but according to given condition it should be 2 at the origin.

Comment: It seems a Kepler parabolic motion and in this case the modulus of the velocity is the same at any point : exactly the escape velocity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_trajectory#Velocity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTICE:** Below I derive the acceleration and velocity vectors.  However, I end up with the same problem you had in your question -- plugging in the point $(0,0)$ and the initial acceleration vector into the acceleration formula, I get an initial speed of $\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}$.  My guess is that this exercise has an **inconsistent** set of initial conditions.  I welcome input from anyone else on this.

---

If $\vec a$ varies inversely with the square of the distance to the focus, then $$\vec a(t) = \frac{k}{\|\vec d(t)\|^2}\hat d(t)$$ where $\vec d(t)$ is the (time-dependent) vector from the point on the parabola to the focus (or vice versa) and $\hat d$ is the *unit* vector pointing from each point on the parabola to the focus each at time $t$.

Let's try to find an explicit form for this.  First off, the distance between the parabola and the focus is $d(t) = \sqrt{(x(t)-0)^2+(y(t)-1/4)^2}$.  But that's just the magnitude (as a function of time $t$).  The direction is given by $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(0-x(t))^2+(1/4 - y(t))^2}}((0-x(t))\hat x+(1/4-y(t))\hat y)$$

Plugging those into the above we get $$\begin{align}\vec a(t) &= \left(\frac{k}{(x(t)-0)^2+(y(t)-1/4)^2}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{(0-x(t))^2+(1/4 - y(t))^2}}((0-x(t))\hat x+(1/4-y(t))\hat y) \\ &= \frac{k}{((-x(t))^2+(1/4 - y(t))^2)^{3/2}}((-x(t))\hat x+(1/4-y(t))\hat y)\end{align}$$

We can then figure out $k$ by plugging in value of $\vec a(t)$ that we're given.

$$\vec a(t_0) = \hat y = \frac{k}{((-0)^2+(1/4 - 0)^2)^{3/2}}((-0)\hat x+(1/4-0)\hat y) = 16k\hat y \\ \implies k=1/16$$

With this we can just plug in to get the acceleration of the particle at $(1,1)$:

$$\vec a(t_1) = \frac{1/16}{((-1)^2+(1/4 - 1)^2)^{3/2}}((-1)\hat x+(1/4-1)\hat y) = \frac{4}{125}(-\hat x-3/4\hat y) = \require{enclose}\enclose{roundedbox}{-\frac{4}{125}\hat x-\frac{3}{125}\hat y}$$

---

We can parametrize the position vector by some parameter $\tau$.  Let's try it:

$$\vec r(\tau(t)) = x(\tau(t))\hat x+y(\tau(t))\hat y = x(\tau(t))\hat x + (x(\tau(t)))^2\hat y$$

The reason I explicitly wrote $\tau$ as a function of $t$ is that now we can use the chain rule to differentiate this wrt $t$:

$$\vec v(t) = \frac{d\vec r(\tau(t))}{dt} = \frac{d\vec r(\tau)}{d\tau}\frac{d\tau}{dt} = \frac{d\tau}{dt}(x'(\tau)\hat x + 2x(\tau)x'(\tau)\hat y) = \frac{d\tau}{dt}\frac{dx(\tau)}{d\tau}(\hat x+2x(\tau)\hat y) = \frac{dx(\tau(t))}{dt}(\hat x+2x(\tau)\hat y) = v_x(t)(\hat x+2x(\tau)\hat y)$$

So then the velocity at the point $(1,1)$ is $$\vec v(t_1)  = v_x(t_1)(\hat x+2(1)\hat y) = v_x(t_1)(\hat x+2\hat y)$$

Let's differentiate this again and see what happens.  $$\vec a(t) = \frac{d\vec v(t)}{dt} = \frac{dv_x(t)}{dt}\hat x + \frac{dv_y(t)}{dt}\hat y = \frac{dv_x(t)}{dt}\hat x + 2\frac{d(v_x(t)x(\tau))}{dt}\hat y = \frac{dv_x(t)}{dt}\hat x + 2\left(\frac{dv_x(t)}{dt}x(\tau) + v_x(t)\frac{dx(\tau(t))}{dt}\right)\hat y = \frac{dv_x(t)}{dt}\hat x + 2\left(\frac{dv_x(t)}{dt}x(\tau) + (v_x(t))^2\right)\hat y$$

Now let's plug in the values we have find acceleration at $(1,1)$.  Then we get $$a_x(t_1) = -\frac{4}{125} = \frac{dv_x(t_1)}{dt} \\ a_y(t_1) = -\frac{3}{125} = 2\left(\frac{dv_x(t_1)}{dt}x(\tau(t_1)) + (v_x(t_1))^2\right) = 2\left(-\frac{4}{125}(1)+(v_x(t_1))^2\right)$$

But this implies that $$v_x(t_1) = \pm\frac{1}{5\sqrt{2}}$$  Because we know that the particle is travelling around the parabola in the rightward direction we know that we have to take the positive value.  With that we see that the velocity vector at the point $(1,1)$ is $$\require{enclose}\enclose{roundedbox}{\vec v(t_1) = \frac{1}{5\sqrt{2}}\left(\hat x + 2\hat y\right)}$$

Comment: Same problem here. Found acceleration but not velocity. I thought putting obtained values of $a_x$ and $a_y$ at x=1 in $a_{y}=2[v_{x}^2+x.a_{x}]$ What do you think about this?